# Org agenda sort by clocked time

Tags: org-agenda

I want to get a list of recently finished things out of org mode. `org-agenda` and `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` seem like the way to go, however none of the options (see `describe-variable` on this) seem to be pay attention to org-clock. Clocking information is the only real time entry that a lot of the things I do have.

Is there an easy way to get a list of finished tasks ordered by when they were last clocked?

`org-agenda-log-mode` is one approach, but this gives me duplicate entries.

Comment: Interesting question! did you find a solution in the meantime, then pleast post it as an answer!